# google app engine 405 http DELETE with AngularJS $resource

Tags: python, angularjs, google-app-engine

I am using GAE Python (with the webapp2 framework) and AngularJS.

I am have trouble with routes on GAE. In fact I have an action in Angular `$resource` that allows to delete an object in my datastore.

Here's my Angular `$resource` code:

```
deleteImage :
        {
            method      : 'DELETE',
            isArray     :  false,
            format      : '.json',
            url         : '/api/hairdressers/:hrd_id/images/:ima_id',
            params      :
            {
            }
        },
```

When I'm calling this method, that calls this url with the DELETE verb :

```
mysite.com/api/hairdresser/877848/images/5451681
```

In my backend I have a route like :

```
webapp2.Route(r'/api/hairdressers/<hrd_id:(\d+)>/images/<ima_id:(\d+)>', handler=HairdresserRestHandler, handler_method='hairdresser_delete_image', name='HairdresserDeleteImageRestHandler', methods=['DELETE']),
```

This route calls the hairdresser_delete_image method in the HairdresserRestHandler.

But I have a `405 Method Not Allowed` Error message when calling this URL.

I also have others routes which begins with `/api/hairdressers/` but  with others params and verbs. Does anybody know what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The problem I am guessing is in your python server code.

You handler for deleting images should look like this, note that I am defining a function called `delete` not `get` or anything else, this will allow the method to be executed.

```
class HairdresserDeleteImageRestHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
def delete(self):
    self.response.write('I will delete an image!')
```

On another side note make sure your urls match, I notice `deleteimage` in your Route path but not in the url you are calling `/api/hairdresser/877848/images/5451681`

Comment: Thanks you for your answer ! I am actually using the handler_method= attribute which allows to redirect the request to a specific function in my handler ! Effectively I had not the same url in my $resource and python code, I correct it but still have the same issue ...